# Write data to influxDB for old date

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to write data into influx db using HTTP API.

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary "poc_test,First_Name=Ajay,Last_Name=Kumar Age=25"
```

it successfully writes data with current point (timestemp) in DB. However I want to write data of two years back and want timestamp should also be of two years back.  if there anyway I can do this, I know i can write it by putting time-stamp to the end of query but I do not know how to convert that date to time-stamp.

e.g.-  i have data like this

```
First_Name:- Ajay
Last_Name:- Kumar

above data belongs to 17/04/2016
```

When i insert this data to influxdb  and I hot a query to

```
select * from poc_test
name: poc_test
time                           First_Name   Last_Name      Age
----                           ----------- ------------- ---------
**2016-04-17T00:00:00.020170822Z** Ajay        Kumar          25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp format is "nanoseconds since unix epoch". So convert your dates/times to nanoseconds, using the tools of your language/environment.

For example, your timestamp "2016-04-17T00:00:00.020170822Z" would be "1460851200020170689" in nanoseconds.

Comment: Do you know any such tool to convert times to nenosecond.  I tried with [link] (https://www.epochconverter.com/) but it is not providing the correct output.

Comment: @AjayKashyap: should be possible using any high-level programming language. I assume, you're not composing those curl commands manually?

Comment: No, as of now i doing poc to write legacy data to influx db, so have composed these command manually for now. but plan to automate it on later stage.